# Why am I only receiving the first address byte? (I2C Protocol)

Tags: i2c, c, avr

Expecting the slave to ACKnowledge and return data, but it does not. [This is my protocol](https://gist.github.com/SensationSama/c60253c8553caf29f7353a725ee42fc4). [This is my Datasheet](https://ams.com/eng/content/download/686523/1787697/file/iAQ-core_Datasheet_EN_v1.pdf).

Also FYI I'm on an Arduino Fio but I am not inheriting the Arduino library.

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <uart.h>
#include <i2c_master.h>

#define LED PB5

#define I2C_READ 0x5A

char buffer[1];

//char data[9];
uint16_t val = 0;
uint8_t status = 0;


void getVal()
{
  if(i2c_start(I2C_READ))
    {
        uart_puts("Start ");

        val = ((uint8_t)i2c_read_ack())<<8; 
        val |= i2c_read_ack();

    status = ((uint8_t)i2c_read_nack());

      i2c_stop();

    } else
  {
        uart_puts("Error");

        i2c_stop();
    }
}

int main(void)
{
  init_uart(57600);
  i2c_init();

  DDRB = _BV(5);

    for(;;)
    {

      getVal();

            itoa(status, buffer, 10); //convert decimal to string base 10
            uart_puts(buffer);

      PORTB = 0xFF;
      _delay_ms(500);
      PORTB = 0x00;
      _delay_ms(500);
    }
    return 0;   /* never reached */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

(Acknowledging this is an old question.) The TI article "[Troubleshooting I2C Bus Protocol](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/scaa106/scaa106.pdf?ts=1610332691462&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F)", suggests several common reasons for no ACK:

```
1. Timing
2. Missing / Unexpected SCL pulses
3. Incomplete 8 bit block
4. Missing Bytes
5. False slave address
6. Unsuccessful address change
```